# List of inherited objects

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a very basic question re: inheritance. I am new to this.

I have a base class:

```
public class base1
{
    public int common {get; set;}
}
```

I have a bunch of derived classes, two of them being

```
public class derived1 : base1
{
    public int prop1 {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class derived2 : base1
{
    public int prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use these in a third class like so, but i get an error:

```
public class usageclass
{
    public List<base1> Data;

    public usageclass()
    {
        Data = new List<base1>();
        derived1 d1 = new derived1();
        d1.common = 0;
        d1.prop1 = 1;
        Data.Add(d1);

        derived2 d2 = new derived2();

        d2.common = Data[0].common + 10;
        d2.prop2 = Data[0].prop1 + 10;  //<--- this line doesn work.  see below.
        Data.Add(d2);
    }
}
```

In the Watch Window or Object Explorer pointed to `Data[0]`, i can see `prop1`, however if i type `Data[0].prop1`, it tells me that `prop1` isn't there.  I'm guessing that its because i have `Data` as a list of `base1`, rather than derived classes, but how do i achieve this?  My ultimate goal is to have `usageclass` have a property that is a type of `List` of different objects, and my thought was that having them be derived from same base class can allow for this.  and why am i able to see everything in object explorer, but not when typing it out.

Thank you!

Comment: I think what you need to do is when accessing the list elements, you will have to inspect the type with something like .GetType(), then cast your object to the correct derived type and you should have your properties

Comment: `Data` is a `List<base1>`, and `base1` does not have a `.prop1` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the deal, let's play this with concrete things.

1. You have a list of animals.
2. You add a frog, and a cat
3. Then you try to set the claws property of the first animal.

How is anyone going to know it's a cat? Chances are it won't be.

You will need to test for the derived type, and cast accordingly

**Cast**

```
var cat = (Cat)someRandomAnimal; // if it's not a cat you will get a run-time error
```

**as operator**

```
var cat = someRandomAnimal as cat; 
if (cat != null)
   cat.Claws - 4;
```

**is operator**

```
if(someRandomAnimal is Cat)
   ((Cat)someRandomAnimal).Claws = 3;
```

**Pattern matching with is operator** [C# 7.0+](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is)

> expr is type varname

```
if(someRandomAnimal is Cat cat)
   cat.Claws = 4;
```